# How many byte alignment for arm?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, alignment

I am programming C on a arm cortex cpu with gcc-arm-none-eabi. I know it is 4-byte alignment by test and google.

But is there any macro or variable which defines how many bytes alignment it is? I need know in case someday this program may be port for another cpu.

Comment: Take a look at [#pragma pack(n)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.4/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html)

Comment: There is no single alignment. Different data-types have different alignment.

Comment: alignment has little to do with portability.

Comment: Beyond the obvious "alignment of what?" as mentioned, you're using an ARM EABI configuration of GCC, therefore if you want to know ABI details you merely need refer to the ARM EABI - this particular aspect is covered by [the procedure call standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf).

Comment: @LPs: That is compiler-specific. OP should use `_Alignas`/`_Alignof`. And use proper marshalling with shifts.

Comment: Sounds like an XY-problem. Normally your code should not rely on that unless it is a hardware-driver. Amd there are very different ARM Cortex CPUs. From M0 to A57 (iirc).

Comment: @Olaf I agree, if c11 can be used.

Comment: @LPs: gcc supports these features since some years now (IIRC even before C11 was released). Anyway, I think it is an XY-problem and there is no actual need even for these features. But without more information we'll never know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trick to find the alignment of a particular data type is to pack it in a struct with a char:

```
#define LONG_ALIGNMENT (sizeof (struct {char a, long b}) - sizeof (long))
#define INT_ALIGNMENT  (sizeof (struct {char a, int b}) - sizeof (int))
```